# Could not resolve placeholder for JavaFX application with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javafx, java-8, application.properties

I have a problem using Spring boot with JavaFX. I have the following error when starting my new application:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.application.ui.title' in value "${spring.application.ui.title}"

I follow this tutorial: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/11/tutorial-reactive-spring-boot-a-javafx-spring-boot-application/ to create it.

So here are my classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AgricultureApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(ApplicationStartUp.class,args);
    }

}


public class ApplicationStartUp extends Application {

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AgricultureApplication.class).run();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(){
        applicationContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
        applicationContext.publishEvent(new StageReadyEvent(primaryStage));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

@Component
public class StageInitializer implements ApplicationListener<StageReadyEvent> {


    private final String applicationTitle;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public StageInitializer(@Value("${spring.application.ui.title}") String applicationTitle, ApplicationContext applicationContext){
        super();
        this.applicationTitle = applicationTitle;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }


    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(StageReadyEvent stageReadyEvent) {
        final Stage primaryStage = stageReadyEvent.getStage();
        try {

            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(new ClassPathResource("/main.fxml").getURL());
            fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(aClass -> applicationContext.getBean(aClass));
            Parent parent = fxmlLoader.load();

            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle(applicationTitle);
            primaryStage.show();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public class StageReadyEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

public StageReadyEvent(Stage stage) {
    super(stage);
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return (Stage) this.getSource();
}
```

}

This is **application.properties** file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./AgricultureRentDb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.main.web-application-type=none
spring.application.ui.title = "Test"

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

And my **POM.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->

    </parent>

    <groupId>gtech</groupId>
    <artifactId>agriculturerent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.20.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>16-ea+1</version>

        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my project strucutre:

[image]

I think spring doesn't recognize application.properties file and i do not why, i've tried to add even the @PropertySource annotation and put absolute path to the application.properties file or to put it as classpath.

Just for notice that when i follow the tutorial i am using java 8 instead of java 11, but i do not think that's making the problem.

**EDITED**:
Here is my github link for the project: https://github.com/Dilyan-Galabov/Agriculture

Can you please help me to provide the problem, thank you in advance :)!

Comment: Double-check that `application.properties` is being deployed to the build folder (by default `target/classes`).

Comment: Very interesting @James_D i can not find it there hmm..Are u sure "application.properties" should be there?

Comment: So that's the issue (or at least, the most immediate cause of the problem, there may be other issues). Your build for some reason is not deploying the `application.properties` file. This is alluded to in the now-deleted answer, but that is certainly on the right track.

Comment: But i removed the unnecessary resources in the pom and nothing happens in the both ways(to stay in the pom and to be removed).

Comment: Are the FXML files being deployed to `target/classes`? What happens if you include the `resources` and fix the `<directory>` entry?\

Comment: No nothing from the resources folder is not deployed to target/classes. I try to include resource from maven but nothing happens. Sorry for asking but what do you mean fixing the <directory> entry?

Comment: I just mean what was said in the deleted answer.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't help to me.

Comment: You replaced `<directory>resources</directory>` with `<directory>src/main/resources</directory>` and you still don't see the FXML and properties files deployed when you do your maven build?

Comment: Yes i did it, but still doesn't see the FXML and properties files deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly @James_D found there is a problem copying the resources files to the target folder. Actually they are not copied anyway even if i add this to my pom.xml:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
</resources>
```

Even if i try to set different targetPath the problem occurs(doesn't copying the files to targetPath) and actually  i think that maven does not read that code in the pom and i do not know why this is happening.